# I want to extend an object but I want to have one table

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have two models

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {
   protected long uid
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class User extends Person {
   protected String username
}
```

As you can see I want to have in one table. Pretty standard thing. Is it possible in play 2.0 ? I`m sick of this evolution thing. It's nice to have a way to upgrade and downgrade db but I can't to such simple things. Or am I missing something ? Do I need auto ddl to achieve that ?